# JasperReports does not generate jasper file from jrxml

Tags: eclipse, jasper-reports, ireport

I'm  tryng to generate a *jasper* file from a *jrxml* file in *iReport*, I'm using a version installed in *Eclipse*.

My jrxml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 5.6.1.final using JasperReports Library version 5.6.1  -->
<!-- 2014-10-01T07:50:10 -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Blank_A4_1" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="c7223858-c808-485b-9ffa-11b9691e2622">
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <detail>
        <band height="125" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="-1" y="0" width="181" height="30" uuid="62caa303-f0cd-45b2-88d5-466bd3c83793"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font pdfFontName="" pdfEncoding="Cp1252" isPdfEmbedded="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[É]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

My jasper file compiled

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 5.6.1.final using JasperReports Library version 5.6.1  -->
<!-- 2014-10-01T07:57:18 -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Blank_A4_1" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="c7223858-c808-485b-9ffa-11b9691e2622">
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <detail>
        <band height="125" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="-1" y="0" width="181" height="30" uuid="62caa303-f0cd-45b2-88d5-466bd3c83793"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font pdfFontName="" pdfEncoding="Cp1252" isPdfEmbedded="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[�]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

I've tryed to change the setting in *Eclipse* like file codding or setting in the *eclipse.ini* to **UTF-8** enconding and nothing changed.

My operationg systema is *Windows 8.1* and I need to use words with accent.

Comment: Change `pdfEncoding` attribute.

Comment: For all fields? And What kind of `pdfEncoding`? Because I selected before `CP1252 (Western European ANSI aka WinAnsi)` and nothing changed